# Data encrypted due to ransomware named CERBER attack

Tags: encryption

Back in 2016 all of my data on my laptop hard drive was encrypted by the **CERBER ransomware**. I refused to pay Ransome money to hacker.

I have all of my important data preserved in an external hard disk. After 4 years now, I am hoping that some solution is there to decrypt my data.

In these data, there are my childhood images which are once in a lifetime memories.

*Please guys I'll appreciate any kinda help. If you are professional then any premium support would work too.*

Can't wait to hear from you guys.

Thank you so much in advanced,
Siddharth shah

Comment: You did not mention what version of CERBER you were affected by, but have you seen this: https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1114221-downloading-and-using-the-trend-micro-ransomware-file-decryptor#cerberDecryption?

Comment: It's is just CERBER. Very beginning of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for some **tool** to **decrypt** your **encrypted files** and if your extension of those encrypted files is something like

***{10 random characters}.cerber*,**

Well, you are in luck!. There's a decryptor tool available. Here's the direct link :
[Trend micro decryptor](http://solutionfile.trendmicro.com/solutionfile/Ransomware%20Decryption%20Tool/RansomwareFileDecryptor%201.0.1668%20MUI.zip)

Good luck!